# Code reported date change in SQL case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-view

```
CASE  
   WHEN CAST([SYS_Created_On] as time) >= CAST('16:00' as time) 
      THEN DATEADD(dd, 1, CAST([SYS_Created_On] AS DATE))
      ELSE CAST([SYS_Created_On] AS DATE)  
END AS [Reported Date],
CASE 
   WHEN CAST([resolved_at] as time) >= CAST('16:00' as time) 
      THEN DATEADD(dd, 1, AS([resolved_at] AS DATE)) 
      ELSE CAST([resolved_at] AS DATE) 
END AS [Resolved Date]
```

I get data from Monday - Friday everyday after 4PM. Can someone help me how to code this to be if the reported date is Friday after 4 or  Saturday  or Sunday have a reported date of Monday.

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific functionality used...)

Comment: @jarlh - I use MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly,
you need to have a Reported Date as on coming Monday, in case the data received and the time is after 4:00 PM,
or
`SYS_Created_On` is a Saturday or Sunday
**you need to get the date corresponding to Monday**

While there are different ways which are more elegant (in the sense that lesser code), the following is more descriptive.

```
CASE  
    WHEN CAST([SYS_Created_On] as time) >= CAST('16:00' as time) and DATENAME(WEEKDAY,CAST([SYS_Created_On] AS DATE)) = 'Friday' 
      THEN DATEADD(dd, 3, CAST([SYS_Created_On] AS DATE))
    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,CAST([SYS_Created_On] AS DATE)) = 'Saturday' 
      THEN DATEADD(dd, 2, CAST([SYS_Created_On] AS DATE))
    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,CAST([SYS_Created_On] AS DATE)) = 'Sunday' 
      THEN DATEADD(dd, 1, CAST([SYS_Created_On] AS DATE))
    WHEN CAST([SYS_Created_On] as time) >= CAST('16:00' as time) 
      THEN DATEADD(dd, 1, CAST([SYS_Created_On] AS DATE))
      ELSE CAST([SYS_Created_On] AS DATE)  
END AS [Reported Date],
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But a small correction I need to have either or both reported date,  resolved date  as on coming Monday. I would say this code gives a better solution. But, I would like to do it lesser code =D thanks srinika

Comment: For the resolved date, you can continue the same logic. For lesser code thing , you need to provide with the table creation script, sample data insert scripts etc. for me to write and test.